# Symfony2: Check user authentication based on path

Tags: php, symfony, authentication

in Symfony2, is it possible to check if user is authenticated to access the URl he requested.
What I want to do is, i dont want to allow a logged in user to go back to registration or login or recover password pages.

here is my security.yml:

```
    access_control:
    - { path: ^/signup/, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY && !IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY}
    - { path: ^/register/, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY && !IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY}
    - { path: ^/recover/, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY && !IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY}
```

but this is showing, access denied page to current user. So i think it would be nice if I can redirect the user to home page on such request, by checking if he is not allowed. Can I check by providing path that user is authenticated or not in listener?

```
    public function onKernelResponse(FilterResponseEvent $event)
    {
     $request = $event->getRequest();
     $path = $request->getPathInfo();

     if($this->container->get('security.context')->getToken() != null) {
       // To check if user is authenticated or anonymous
       if( ($this->container->get('security.context')->getToken() instanceof UsernamePasswordToken) &&
        ($this->container->get('security.context')->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY') == true) ) {
         // HOW TO CHECK PATH ?
        // set response to redirect to home page
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Why do you use a `onKernelResponse` event instead of the [kernel.request.event](http://www.symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_kernel/introduction.html#the-kernel-request-event)?

Comment: yes, you are right. I should check it in kernel.request.event, thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### The `security.access_map` service

The configuration of **security.access_control** is processed by ...

```
SecurityBundle\DependencyInjection\SecurityExtension
```

... which creates RequestMatchers for the routes (path,hosts,ip,...) and then invokes the service's [`add()`](https://github.com/symfony/SecurityBundle/blob/2.3/DependencyInjection/SecurityExtension.php#L182) method with the matcher, the allowed roles and the channel (i.e. https ).

The service is usually used by i.e. the [AccessListener](https://github.com/symfony/Security/blob/master/Http/Firewall/AccessListener.php#L34).

> You can use the **security.access_map** service to access the
>   **security.access_control** parameters in your application.

The class used for the security.access_map service is defined by the parameter [**security.access_map.class**](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.3/src/Symfony/Bundle/SecurityBundle/Resources/config/security_listeners.xml#L33) and defaults to

> [`Symfony\Component\Security\Http\AccessMap`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.3/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/AccessMap.php) ( implements
>   [AccessMapInterface](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.3/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/AccessMapInterface.php) )

You can use the parameter **security.access_map.class** to override the service with a custom class (must implement *AccessMapInterface*):

```
# i.e. app/config/config.yml

parameters:
    security.access_map.class: My\Custom\AccessMap
```

---

### How to access the service

The `security.access_map` service is a **private** service as you can see by it's definition **[here](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/2.3/src/Symfony/Bundle/SecurityBundle/Resources/config/security_listeners.xml#L74)**.

This means you **can't** request it from the container directly like this:

`$this->container->get('security.access_map')`

You will have to **inject** it into another service (i.e. a listener service) explicitly to be able to access it.

---

### A listener example

```
services:
    my_listener:
        class: My\Bundle\MyListenerBundle\EventListener\ForbiddenRouteListener
        arguments: [ @security.access_map ]
        tags:      
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request, method: onKernelRequest }
```

Then you can call the `getPatterns()` method to obtain the RequestMatchers, **allowed roles** and required channel from there.

```
namespace My\Bundle\MyListenerBundle\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\AccessMapInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;

class ForbiddenRouteListener
{

    protected $accessMap;

    public function __construct(AccessMapInterface $access_map)
    {
        $this->accessMap = $access_map;
    }

    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        $request = $event->getRequest();
        $patterns = $this->accessMap->getPatterns($request);

        // ...
```

Comment: I will have to continue with the complete solution lateron - sorry. But this should already give a hint into the right direction.

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanation of access_map service. I still have not tried this, but this will work.

Comment: Thoroughly answered, nice!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help someone. I just catch route name and check if they are in array. If yes just redirect. This is event listener.

services.yml

```
project.loggedin_listener:
      class: Project\FrontBundle\EventListener\LoggedInListener
      arguments: [ "@router", "@service_container" ]
      tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request, method: onKernelRequest }
```

listener:

```
namespace Project\FrontBundle\EventListener;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;

class LoggedInListener {
    private $router;
    private $container;

    public function __construct($router, $container)
    {
        $this->router = $router;
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        $container = $this->container;
        $accountRouteName = "_homepage";

        if( $container->get('security.context')->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY') ){

            $routeName = $container->get('request')->get('_route');
            $routes = array("admin_login","fos_user_security_login","fos_user_registration_register","fos_user_resetting_request");
            if(in_array($routeName, $routes)){
                $url = $this->router->generate($accountRouteName);
                $event->setResponse(new RedirectResponse($url));
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: In symfony 2.6 security.context is deprecated, need use security.authorization_checker

Answer (score 0):

You can do not only inside security.yml options, but also via controller, like this:

```
if($securityContext->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED')) {
      return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('homepage'));
}
```

Comment: It works. But this way I have to add this condition in all controller from which I want to redirect back to home page.

Comment: Sure. But you can also use the condition as before filter. http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/event_dispatcher/before_after_filters.html