# symfony2: check isGranted for a route

Tags: symfony

supposed having certain route string like "/path/index.html" protected by firewall, how to chek whether current user is able to access it?

Thanks in advance!

I am sorry, I should have been more explicit: I have an array of route names and I construct a menu. A lot of users with different roles can access a page with this menu. The purpose is to show only accessible liks in this menu for a particular user.

Something like:

```
'security_context'->'user'->isGranted('/path/index.html')
```

Comment: Answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20193248/symfony2-check-user-authentication-based-on-path

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This answer is based on your comments:
You should get the roles needed to access that route.to that you need access to the `security.access_map` service which is private.so it has to be injected directly.e.g: you can create a `path_roles` service like such that you can get the roles for a certain path:

```
namespace Acme\FooBundle;

class PathRoles
{
    protected $accessMap;

    public function __construct($accessMap)
    {
        $this->accessMap = $accessMap;
    }

    public function getRoles($path)
    { //$path is the path you want to check access to

        //build a request based on path to check access
        $request = Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request::create($path, 'GET');
        list($roles, $channel) = $this->accessMap->getPatterns($request);//get access_control for this request

        return $roles;
    }
}
```

now declare it as a service:

```
services:
    path_roles:
        class: 'Acme\FooBundle\PathRoles'
        arguments: ['@security.access_map']
```

now use that service in your controller to get the roles for the path and construct your menu based on those roles and isGranted.i.e:

```
  //code from controller
  public function showAction(){
      //do stuff and get the link path for the menu,store it in $paths
      $finalPaths=array();
      foreach($paths as $path){
      $roles = $this->get('path_roles')->getRoles($path);
      foreach($roles as $role){
          $role = $role->getRole();//not sure if this is needed
          if($this->get('security.context')->isGranted($role)){
              $finalPaths[] = $path;
              break;
          }
      }
     //now construct your menu based on $finalPaths
      }
  }
```

Comment: sourced from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20193248/symfony2-check-user-authentication-based-on-path

Comment: it works only with path like '/home', not with route name like 'homepage', right? how to modify it to work with routes?

Comment: @OlegAbrazhaev You can inject the RouterInterface into the PathRoles service, then use $router->getRouteCollection()->get($routeName)->getPath() to get the path

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`security.access_control`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#understanding-how-access-control-works) configuration option:

```
securty:
    access_control:
        - { path: "^/path/index.html$", roles: ROLE_SOME_ROLE}
```

Or simply check that manually from within your controller:

```
class SomeController extends Controller {
    public function indexAction() {
        if (!$this->get('security.context')->isGranted(...)) {
            throw new AccessDeniedException(...);
        }

        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for an answer. Sorry, I should have been more explicit: I have an array of route names and I construct menu. A lot of users with different roles can access a page with this menu. The purpose is to show only accessible liks in this menu for a particular user.