# Get minimum ROLE required for a path from TWIG

Tags: symfony, twig

I'd like to do something like that in Twig.

```
{% if isGranted('routename') %}
<a href='{{path('routename'}}'>value</a> 
{%else%}
{{value}}
{%endif%}
```

I think I need to build a Twig Extension, so I'd like to know if is there in PHP a clean way to accessing the minimum role required for a given route path, taking this data from the security.yml.

I have been trying the  security.access_map solution, but although the $request has all the server parameters (others are null) , $patterns is an array with 2 null elements....

```
$request = $this->requestStack->getCurrentRequest()->create($path, 'GET'); 
$patterns = $this->accessMap->getPatterns($request);
```

Comment: I don't know the use case details, but I think you can use a custom [Voter](http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/voters.html) (that contains the logic used to grant the access to specific routes to specific users) to then be able to use it in twig like: `{% if isGranted('ROUTE_NAME') %}` or `{% if isGranted('ROUTE_GROUP') %}`.

Comment: But how to check the routename without writing it again on the Voter. I want that the voter check any route name  against the security.yml.

Comment: As I previously said I don't know the details and probably it would be better if you update your question adding more details about what you want to achieve.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25015763/symfony2-check-isgranted-for-a-route.. I think this is what you are looking for.  You could implement as a Twig extension or even as a rendered controller.

Comment: Thanks but, although the $request has all the server parameter (the other are null) , $patterns is an array with 2 null elements....
      $request = $this->requestStack->getCurrentRequest()->create($path, 'GET');
         $patterns = $this->accessMap->getPatterns($request);