# Controller check in advance if user can access a route + parameters

Tags: php, symfony, redirect, twig

I've got a notification system where a route name is stored in the DB along with some a list of parameters used to build a URL. When a user clicks on a notification, these values are recalled and are passed into the router to generate a URL for the user to be redirected to.

A notification has the following structure (simplified structure, there is some inheritance at play here)

```
class Notification {

    /** @var int */
    protected $id;
    
    /** @var Uid */
    protected $uid;

    /** @var string */
    protected $title;

    /** @var string */
    protected $routeName;

    /** @var array|null */
    protected $routeParameters;

    /** @var DateTime */
    protected $date;

    /** @var DateTime|null */
    protected $read;
}
```

However instead of blindly passing these parameters into the clickable object on screen, they pass through the a `redirectAction()` defined in the `NotificationController`.

```
<a href="{{ path('notification_action') }}?uid={{ notification.uid }}">{{ notification.title }}</a>
```

This so that I can do a couple things.

1. Mark the notification as read
2. Make sure that the user who clicked the notification is the user who the notification was delivered to (otherwise throw an `AccessDeniedException`)
3. Make sure that old links are handled nicely `<-- the issue`

So far, there is a section in my controller that reads the following:

```
/**
 * @Route("/notification/action", name="notification_action")
 * @param Request $request
 * @param RouterInterface $router
 * @return RedirectResponse|Response
 */
public function redirectAction(Request $request, RouterInterface $router) {

    // * $notification gets recalled from the DB from the 'uid' in the request params
    // * Validation is applied to the notification (check if exists, check if for the correct user)
    // * Notification is marked as read with the current timestamp

    try {
        $url = $router->generate($notification->getRoute(), $notification->getParameters() ?? []);
    } catch(RouteNotFoundException | MissingMandatoryParametersException | InvalidParameterException $e) {
        return $this->render('notification/broken_action.html.twig');
    }

    return $this->redirect($url);
}
```

This is in order to attempt to generate a route and nicely handle a route that either

- a) doesn't exist
- b) no longer works with older parameters.

This works great if I were to change the definition of a route in the future, but it doesn't handle checking if the user has permission to *access the route*. This includes:

- Checking if the user has the appropriate role to access the route (defined in `security.yaml`)
- Checking if they user is denied access by either the `@Security` annotation or a voter
- Validating parameters interpreted by the the `@ParamConverter` (such as when an entity may not exist anymore causing a 404)
- Handling a thrown exception such as `AccessDeniedException` or `NotFoundHttpException` from logic within the action itself

---

I'm having trouble coming up with a way that I can validate these things before redirecting the user to the `$url`.

So far all I've come up with is performing a dummy request and seeing if that works before then redirecting the user, but that is yuck for obvious reasons (double request will have extended load times, potentially triggering an action in the background, etc.)

Is there a way that I can check for these things in an efficient way before sending the user to the generated URL? I'm happy to let logic within the action itself slide through validation, as most of the time I tend to avoid this in favour for voters or use of the `@Security` and `@ParamConverter` annotations instead. It's just a nice to have for edge cases.

...or I'm open to other ideas on better ways to handle clicking on a notification!

Comment: Going through some posts on SO, it seems the only way is actually doing an extra request to be able to determine the granted roles - [related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25046487/446594)

Comment: That method only tells me which roles are required. It doesn't tell me if they are denied access via the `@Security` annotation, or if `@ParamConverter` couldn't find a parameter.

Comment: It's an interesting question assuming that I understand it correctly.  Among other things you want to acess the firewall directly and see if the user has access to the route.  I don't know of any easy way to do that.  Why not just do the redirect and let the security system do it's thing?  Under what conditions would the user legally attempt to access a route to which they are denied?  In other words, do you even need to handle the exception specifically?  If you really need to then consider a custom exception handler.

Comment: It's mainly for the sake of displaying a better error message for UX reasons. Clicking on an old notification or one whose transaction had already completed is jarring when you are smacked with a 403 FORBIDDEN or similarly a 404. It's a dumb issue to have but it's a small thing that makes the app just that little bit nicer for the user.

Comment: @Cerad you mention custom a exception handler. How would this work? I haven't made one before. Assuming you catch any exception a route may throw, that may not work, because it is also normal to throw a 404 or a 403 if a user where to the wrong page (not via the notification)

Comment: It's basically just a [kernel exception listener](https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/error_pages.html#overriding-the-default-errorcontroller).  You can do things like checking to see if it was thrown by your notification stuff.  But again, are there actually cases where the notification will fail?  Besides of course if the user is trying to mess with you?

Comment: All I really need to track is if the redirect from clicking on a notification failed. Could be any exception, so long as the origin is from `/notification/action?uid=xxx`