# How to check required user role

Tags: php, security, symfony

When I have security settings like this

```
security:
    firewalls:
        main:
            # ...
    access_control:
        - { path: ^/secure, roles: ROLE_USER }
        - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

How can I fetch the required role for a request, e.g. `ROLE_USER` user if `/secure` is accessed or `ROLE_ADMIN` for `/admin` in a Controller or Service?

Comment: I updated my answer because I found a better solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you **really need** to do it that way:

Get your current route in your controller:

```
$request = $this->container->get('request');
$route = $request->get('_route');
```

Read the access control from security.yml:

- Load security.yml: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/config/resources.html
- Parse YAML to php array: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/yaml/introduction.html

**UPDATE!**

I found out that there is a service called `security.access_map`, which you can use.

Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20194159/982075

**/UPDATE**

Get the role the route needs and check in your controller if the role is granted:

```
if ($this->get('security.context')->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')) {
    //Do Something
}
```

## Do something else

Just place this in your controllers as you see fit:

```
if ($this->get('security.context')->isGranted('ROLE_SMTH')) {
    //Do Something
}
```

and/or write an access denied listener for redirects when a role is not granted to avoid 403 messages.
Tutorial on that: http://www.insanevisions.com/articles/view/symfony-2-access-denied-listener