# symfony verify if a route is granted / assess a return redirectToRoute statement

Tags: php, security, symfony, redirect, try-catch

I have a symfony2 controller in which I want to do the following:

```
try {
    return $this->redirect($request->headers->get('referer'));
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    return $this->redirectToRoute('home');
}
```

It does not work. The idea is that given what happens in this controller, the user's permissions might change. So I want to know if he can still access the current route, if yes, redirect to current route, if not, redirect to home.

How can I do that ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25015763/symfony2-check-isgranted-for-a-route and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20193248/symfony2-check-user-authentication-based-on-path

Comment: is the code showing here relevant to the question you are asking ? it doesn't seem so to me

Comment: the second link about access_map would be worth investigating. Did not have the time yet

Comment: You might have to way to do this:
The first one is on this link (Already given vu @kapa89 [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25015763/symfony2-check-isgranted-for-a-route](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25015763/symfony2-check-isgranted-for-a-route)
The second option is to create a [custom voter](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/voters_data_permission.html) to do this which will check this manually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see a good way to do that. The problem is, you need to ask the whole security component, which uses requestlistners to deny access. Unfortunately the Accesstoken is only generated once, so if you ask requestlistners again, it wont use the new user-rights.

The best idea, might be to make the redirect and then catch the Exception (with an exceptionListener )  where it really happen and to an redirect then.

Comment: that's what I ended up doing... far simpler