# How to match url's against Symfony's security access control

Tags: php, symfony, acl

Hi everyone im new to Symfony and have a simple problem.

In the `security.yml` file I've set some access controlled paths:

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: .*settings, roles: ROLE_USER }
    - { path: ^/$, roles: ROLE_USER }
    - { path: ^/.*, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

That so far works as i want to.

Now Im building a menu and want to hide show the navigation items based on its access, so how can i fetch this information?

There has to be some function like:

```
$securityContext->isUrlGranted( $this->generateUrl('homepage') );
```

Thanks for your help.

**EDIT**

Example:

```
// current user is ROLE_ADMIN:
$acl->isUrlGranted( 'foo/bar' ); // true
$acl->isUrlGranted( 'login' ); // true

// IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY
$acl->isUrlGranted( 'login' ); // true
$acl->isUrlGranted( 'something/else' ); // false

// ROLE_USER
$acl->isUrlGranted( 'settings/profile' ); // true
$acl->isUrlGranted( 'foo/bar' ); // false
```

etc..

Comment: I think you can look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25015763/symfony2-check-isgranted-for-a-route

Comment: @AndreySobkanyuk Thanks, thats pretty much what i've searched for but i think that solution is an overkill for such a simple need.. The Symfony way of doing this seems to configure the menu manually based on the roles, wich I think is completely stupid because this way you define everything twice... But im going to stick with that because I don't have the resources and time to implement another ACL or extend symfonies build in one.

Comment: I suppose that unfortunately it's the only solution. I can post this as an standalone answer if you want.

Comment: @AndreySobkanyuk Do that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now there is no simple ways in `Symfony` get this information via one function.

To get it you can access `security.access_control` parameters in your application using `security.access_map` service.

But you can't request it from the container directly, because it's a private service, so have to inject it into another service.

And only then you will be able to write your own `Twig` extension with `isUrlGranted()` function.

P.S.: My answer is only a short summary of well written [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20194159/4399592) on the similar question.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using twig in your view ( which should contain the menu ), you can test the user role with:

```
    {# my menu.twig.html #}

    {% if app.security.isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN', app.user) %}
        ....
    {% endif %}
```

You can do the same in your controller by the way, but i supposed that your layout contains the menu so i posted a twig answer. Tell me if it's relevant and helpful for you.

Comment: I use something like this in my standard_layout for menu: {% if display %}
                                                    {% for admin in group.items if item_count == 0 %}
                                                        {% if admin.hasroute('list') and admin.isGranted('LIST') %}
                                                            {% set item_count = item_count+1 %}
                                                        {% endif %}
                                                    {% endfor %}
                                                {% endif %}

Comment: Its not the solution im searching for, I configured the role access already in the `security.yml` im looking for a solution that uses the data configured there. I don't want to define everything twice..

Comment: Can you show us where and how you construct your menu please?